# Atom editor installed on MacOS but doesn't show up in Applications folder, terminal

Tags: macos, atom-editor

I can find it from  Spotlight but not in my applications. And after running it, I can open an empty file with atom from the terminal but not some of my old files. The error message is always `atobm:  bad character` followed by the first line on the .py file, character by character.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Atom to the proper Applications folder. After that open Atom and under the Atom menu item select install shell commands. When you reinstall Atom, be sure it's to the /Applications folder and not in an applications folder in your home directory.